# Как запустить программу через её двоичный код

Tags: python

Допустим есть программа test.exe которая просто выводит на экран hello, world. (программа необязательно написана на python)

Нужно средствами python сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
import somemodule

code = open('test.exe', 'wb').read()

somemodule.execute(code)
```

В результате увидим на экране hello, world.
В общем, нужно запустить exe через его двоичный код.

Работа программы похожа на следующий код:

```
import os
os.system('test.exe')
```

Только в данном случае мы уже имеем файл test.exe сохранённый на диске, а моя цель - запустить программу прямо из оперативной памяти. Что-то такое:

```
import somemodule

encoded_code = b"any encode bytes code"

somemodule.execute(encoded_code.decode('my encoding algorithm'))
```

Comment: Средствами Python этого точно не добиться. Есть шанс с помощью ctypes, но во-первых, код запуска для разных операционных систем будет разным, во-вторых, исполняемый код должен быть разным для разных ABI, а в-третьих, этому активно будут сопротивляться антивирусники.

Comment: Чисто технически можно, если допустим ограничиться только Windows. Но по сути придется реализовать свой загрузчик PE модулей (загрузить exe в память, обработать таблицу релокаций, проставить адреса для импортируемых функций). Если не делать разбор EXE файла, а допустим есть бинарный файл с машинным кодом (под конкретную битность системы, без вызовов внешних функций - т.е. никакого ввода-вывода, например, только через получение аргументов и возврат результата), то все немного проще, вроде бы даже видел решения как что-то подобное сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, это невозможно. Так как, подобный функционал может быть использован для взлома системы, его никто предоставлять не будет.

Comment: На C относительно легко делается.