# Как запустить exe в бинарном виде из самого скрипта python

Tags: python

У меня есть exe файл в бинарном виде. Как мне его запустить прямо из скрипта python не сохраняя его на ПК а прямо из кода программы? 
Допускаю что, наверное, нужен ctypes...

Comment: @Abyx, и даже через ctypes?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PYTHON Как запустить программу через её двоичный код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/995237/204271)